# How to extract image names from SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have Wordpress installation based on SQL Server and would like to extract the image names from the field post_content in wp_post. I have tried a lot with patindex, like clause and so on but I cant figure out how to do.

Here's an example of the content on row in the post_content column :

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-133975" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1-1024x682.jpg" alt="" width="604" height="402" /></a>
```

I have about 10 000 records in the table and the content in post_content can contain one or more images.
I would like to extract the image names like this :

/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1.jpg

/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1-1024x682.jpg

Thankful for help.

Comment: First step: Redesign the db so it's not storing html in tables.

Comment: So you want the relative path for each image in your table? Is the domain name consistent or can it vary? Is there anything consistent across everything? Is the first folder in the path always "wp-content"? Reason I am asking is the code can be a LOT simpler if there is a consistent anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to a TVF.

Tired of extracting strings, I modified a parse function to accept two, non-like parameters.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,post_content varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-133975" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1-1024x682.jpg" alt="" width="604" height="402" /></a>')


Select A.ID
      ,ImageSrc = B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.post_content,'.com','"') B
 Where right(B.RetVal,4) in ('.jpg','.png','.gif')
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ImageSrc
1   /wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1.jpg
1   /wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1-1024x682.jpg
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, it worked really good. Now I can delete 210 000 pics from the server that are not used in any post.

Comment: @JohnF Happy it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),data NVARCHAR(500))
INSERT @table VALUES('<a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1.jpg"><img "D:/abc.jpg" class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-133975" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/1-1-1024x682.jpg" alt="" width="604" height="402" /></a>')
DECLARE @images TABLE (ID INT,data NVARCHAR(500),passed INT)
DECLARE @collecter INT = 1

WHILE(@collecter=1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @images 
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(REVERSE(data),CHARINDEX('gpj.',REVERSE(data))+4,500),0 FROM @table
UPDATE @images SET data = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(data,1,CHARINDEX('/',data+'/')-1))+'.jpg' WHERE passed = 0
UPDATE A SET A.data = SUBSTRING(A.data,1,CHARINDEX(B.data,A.data)-1) FROM @table A JOIN @images B ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE passed = 0
UPDATE @images SET passed = 1
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @table GROUP BY data HAVING CHARINDEX('.jpg',data)>0) SET @collecter = 1 ELSE SET @collecter = 0
END

SELECT data FROM @images
```